# HP Pavilion 500 223w Ubuntu server wifi problem

Tags: wireless, hp

I have a HP Pavilion 500 223w and I installed Ubuntu server LTS on it and I cannot get my wifi to work it says  "SET failed on device wlan0 ; No such device."  Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Is this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, or 14.04 ? Please show the relevant output of the commands : inxi -N -z and iwconfig (Install inxi with "sudo apt-get install inxi" if you don't have it).

Comment: It's the latest one, And, Can I install that without internet? and, I do iwconfig ess (network) key (password) and I get "SET failed on device wlan0 ; No such device."

Comment: Please ignore this and any other comment asking about "inxi". There's no need. You can get the hardware information with `lspci` or `lsusb`. But, first of all, make sure a) The hardware exists (WiFi is optional) and b) it isn't disabled in BIOS/UEFI (that being the default). According to HP it's an old Atheros chipset that should just work.

Comment: I ended up installing Ubuntu Desktop and the Wifi works. But, Thanks for the Answer!